# TaskNotSerializable with Spark Dataset transformations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to filter the Spark dataset by one of the fields but as the result of transformations, I receive TaskNotSerializable. Here's how the method looks like:

```
def filterData(input: Dataset[CustomType], idsList: List[Int]): Dataset[CustomType] =
   input.flatMap { record =>
   val filtered = record.data.filter(rec => idsList.contains(rec.id))
   if (filtered.nonEmpty)
     Seq(record.withFields(filtered))
   else
     Iterable.empty
   }
```

I tried to do similar transformations on Spark dataframe and it worked without any issues:

```
input.withColumn("arr", explode($”data”))
  .filter($"arr.id".isin(idsList: _*)) //List(34,81,95)
  .drop("arr")
  .as[CustomType]
```

How dataset transformations could be fixed to avoid this error?

Custom type structure is the following:

```
|-- url: string (nullable = true)

|-- data: array (nullable = true)

|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

|    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = false)

|    |    |-- expiration: long (nullable = false)

|    |    |-- weight: integer (nullable = false)

|-- queryParams: array (nullable = true)

|-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Error serialization stack looks like this:

```
  Serialization stack:

- object not serializable (class: job.DataSink, value: job.DataSink@6dda8f39)

- field (class: job.DataSink$$anonfun$filterData$1, name: $outer, type: class job.DataSink)

- object (class job.DataSink$$anonfun$filterData$1, <function1>)

- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$flatMap$1, name: func$6, type: interface scala.Function1)

- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$flatMap$1, <function1>)

- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, name: func, type: interface scala.Function1)

- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, MapPartitions <function1>, obj#392: schemas.data.CustomType

 +- Scan[obj#383]

 )
```

Comment: Usually when there is `TaskNotSerializable` there is kind of a stack trace made by Spark which indicates what he was trying to serialize when it failed, that way we can see which data structure it was. Can you go through your logs and find it or just post the whole thing and I'll try to find it? It looks something like this `Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: testing, value: testing@2dfe2f00)
    - field (class: testing$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class testing)
    - object (class testing$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
`

Comment: @Filip sure, I've added serialization stack to the question

Comment: I still need more information, but my best guess is what I answered with information available ATM.

Answer (score 0):

From serialization stack I would say that this function is part of `job.DataSink` class and Spark is trying to serialize whole class to send it to worker. You need to implement `Serializable` if you want to make it serializable by Spark.

Comment: True, filterData function can't be serialized. is there a way to optimize the method itself without implementing Serializable?

Comment: It's hard to say what else can be done without the rest of the code. In some cases it's possible to make variable `lazy` inside of the Spark job code which would basically cause Spark to send serialized code to the worker instead of serialized instance of object. Then Spark would initialize object on the worker and call the function. In that case you wouldn't need to implement `Serializable`. Why are you avoiding implementing `Serializable`?

Comment: It's more the code base style question than a preference